# How common is it to include unmedicated patients in first episode psychosis (or any type of psychosis) studies?

Tags: neuroscience, psychosis, ethics

Is anyone familiar with this open access study?

- Radua, J., Borgwardt, S., Crescini, A., Mataix-Cols, D., Meyer-Lindenberg, A., McGuire, P. K., & Fusar-Poli, P. (2012). Multimodal meta-analysis of structural and functional brain changes in first episode psychosis and the effects of antipsychotic medication. *Neuroscience & Biobehavioral Reviews, 36*(10), 2325-2333. doi: [10.1016/j.neubiorev.2012.07.012](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neubiorev.2012.07.012)

I'm surprised by the included studies. 76% of FEP patients in the structural group (965 patients) received antipsychotics, and only 53% of FEP patients in the functional group (362 patients) received medication. I always assumed studies on FEP using medication-naive patients were almost unheard for ethical concerns. Unless I'm mistaken, that's not the case.

"Forty-three studies met inclusion criteria (Fig. 1). Specifically, in the structural meta-analysis, we included 965 FEP subjects (mean age 24, range 15–35 years; 34% females; 76% receiving antipsychotic treatment), matched with 1040 controls (mean age 26, range 15–35 years; 34% females). The cognitive tasks functional imaging cohort included 362 FEP subjects (mean age 26, range 19–36 years; 31% females; 53% receiving antipsychotic treatment)."